# Multimedia playing in Java

Tags: java, audio, multimedia

I need to play multimedia files in Java. I have studied JMF and FMJ, however, both of them have not been updated over several years.

Is there any open-source Java project for multimedia playing?

Thanks.

Comment: FMJ is open source, it just hasn't really been active for a while.  I have used both and am still using JMF in production applications and while it is dated and a pain to work with, it just seems to work, at least for webcams.  Perhaps it hasn't been updated because it is relatively stable?

Comment: One thought might be to try integrating HTML5 within an embedded browser object in Java... might be a neat idea for a project if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: @maple_shaft, because it hasn't been update in a while it has a lot of missing codec which means, the majority of current formats wont play.

Comment: @maple_shaft  Agree that codec advance is the *major* loss of functionality for the JMF, but it has been ***abandoned*** and is not maintained (in fact, the source which used to be available disappeared off Sun's site, before it became Oracle).  But it also suffers from lack of 64 bit natives, support only for web-cams up to 640x480 resolution..

Comment: Note that both JMF and FMJ support new codes/formats via the Service Provider Interface.  It is just a matter of finding a codec for the type of interest, making sure it is implemented using the SPI (basically by adding a text file in the Jar, identifying the methods), and add it to the run-time class-path of the app.  Either API should support the new format as soon as that is done.  BTW - by 'multimedia' you do mean including video, right?  (I'd look to `javax.sound.sampled` & the SPI for pure audio.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using VLCJ (http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/) and made some good experience with it. It embeds a native VLC player into a AWT/Swing application. Since VLC supports many many codecs, I think it's quite a good choice. Unfortunately, you need to have VLC installed.